# How to get data in angular Data tables?

Tags: php, angular, angular7

I am a newbie on angular , I am calling a php api to fetch the data from database
Api is working fine and showing me data on console now i want to print that data on my data table. What Should I do?

here is my .ts file code

```
 fetchRollHeader(){
   var apiurl = 'http://localhost/abc/Controller/abc.php';

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', 'fetchRollHeader');
    data.append('roll_id', this.roll_id);

      return this.http.post<any>(apiurl, data)

          .pipe(map((response: any) => response))
          .subscribe(
                data => {
              if(data['response_type'] != undefined && data['response_type'] == 'Error'){
                data.append('roll_id_demo', this.roll_id_demo);

                    if(data['response'] == 29){
                    }else if(data['response'] == 8 || data['response'] == 9 || data['response'] == 10){
                      this.router.navigate(['login']);
                    }else{
                      alert(data['response_value']);

                    }
                }else{
                  this.customers = data;


                }
                  console.log(data);

                },
                error => {
                    console.log("Error", error);
                }
            ); 
  }
```

and this is how m calling the data in table but no value is showing up

```
<tr  *ngFor="let item of customers" >
      <td   >{{item.roll_id_demo}}</td>
```

Comment: Please only use the tag of the actual angular version you are using

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: i cant show the data in my table {{item.roll_id_demo}} i think might not working

Comment: Does your `console.log` shows some object?

Comment: For starters, don't use the same variable name for two difference things. `data` points to both a `FormData` object and the result coming your HTTP post. Also, the `map` is useless.

Comment: @Batajus yes its showing the data on console

Answer (score -1):

You might not be checking if the value is null in your html page. Try using ngIf on your table. The code will look something like this:

```
<table *ngIf="customers">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of customers">
        <td>{{item.roll_id_demo}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```